# How to search a tree with sunspot & solr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, acts-as-tree, sunspot-rails

I have a model that looks something like this

```
class Post
  acts_as_tree
end
```

What I want to do is conduct a search on the contents of an entire thread of posts, but only return the parent post in the results, and paginate these results.

I've read about facets in sunspot/solr, and while this does return the correct results, they cannot be paginated.

Basically, I want to search a set of posts, but group by their `parent_id`. Is this possible in sunspot/solr?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want to search over a field that is composed of all of a thread's child nodes. You can do this with sunspot's block syntax. If the post is a root node, index all of the node's children (you'll have to implement all_children, which shouldn't be too hard).

```
searchable do
  text :posts do
    all_children.map(&:post_body) unless parent
  end
end
```

Then search over this "posts" text field. Since you only indexed anything for root nodes, these are the only objects that will be returned in your result set.

Comment: I would also suggest you use acts_as_nested_set instead of acts_as_tree. It can handle the all_children call in a single query, whereas acts_as_tree could take many queries to achieve the same thing.